# how to find other machines which are connected same network

Tags: networking, nmap

I tried to find all machines which are connected my modem. I tried 192.168.x.0/24 command on gnome-terminal but it couldn't find any. My brother's laptop and my mobile phone are already connected the modem but this command couldn't find them.

Here is the output :

```
root@tugrul:/home/tugrul# nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-22 01:40 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0050s latency).
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Shenzhen Zowee Technology Co.)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.x
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.40 seconds
```

I also tried `nmap -sn 192.168.6.0/24` but there was no difference:

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.6.0/24
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
MAC Address:  (Shenzhen Zowee Technology Co.)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.15
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: [Please don't use version tags (e.g. `14.04`) unless your issue is only relevant to one version of Ubuntu.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7245/85695)

Comment: That's strange. The command you show should have worked. Are you sure the other devices are on the same network? Is their IP address `192.168.1.XX`?

Comment: Yes, the other devices are connected same modem in my room. But command couldn't find. I'm triying last 2 ours.

Comment: Use `sudo` before the `nmap` command as TCP SYN packets are sent to only ports 80 and 443 when `nmap -sP` is run as unprivileged user..

Comment: I wanna ask one thing, when I start working on terminal, I do sudo su and I work as root. I'm new on Linux. Is not it same?

Comment: @heemayl that might be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @terdon it seems OP is already working as `root`..

Comment: @heemayl ah, yes, I missed that. Still strange though, `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` shows all machines on my network. m.tuğrul could you show us the IPs of the machines you can't find? Don't worry, sharing *internal* IPs (e.g. 192.168.1.10) [is completely safe](http://askubuntu.com/q/435261/85695).

Comment: yes I am already working as a root. I wrote sudo su and I started to work as root

Comment: I addition to what @terdon has asked for could you please run it as `nmap -sn 192.168.6.0/24` as `root` of course..just want to check as `-sP` is deprecated in favor of `-sn`..

Comment: Will I share screenshot @terdon?

Comment: @m.tuğrul no, just copy the text from the terminal and paste it into your answer. I still suspect that these machines are not on the same network somehow, so please also show i) your **internal** IP and ii) the **internal** IP of one of the devices.

Comment: I paste the output as you said

Comment: I already paste  output of process as an ansver and I checked devices. Devices is already connected my modem.

Comment: Thanks (I added it to your question instead) but you still haven't told us the IP you are trying to find. As I said, there is no danger in sharing internal IPs (they are only accessible from inside your network) and it would help us be sure that you're running the right command.

Comment: 192.168.1.2 my brothers machine ip. I know I know but I forgot sharing the ip which I want to find.

Comment: Add the output of `ifconfig` for both systems, also, what OS your brother use?

Comment: my brother use Windows 7, I'm out of city for 5 days. I didn't bring my computer with me, it stayed at home.

Comment: Doesn't work doesn't work I'll be crazy doesn't work. Now 5 machines are connected my modem but I can't find ip address of them on my ubuntu.Please help me.

Comment: hi guys, I found ip adresses on my local network. I wan't ask you one more things. How to connect to other machine via network ports? Is that possible? I know software development (Java).

Answer (score 2):

try arp-scan. install it by `sudo apt install arp-scan`:

`sudo arp-scan -l`

Comment: Doesn't exists other way? I'll try your solution but Can't we do that without tools?

Comment: you'll probably need to run *something*. I'm not sure what you mean with "tools" though.

Comment: Is arp-scan a tool like nmap developed by some guy or I understand wrong this?

Comment: every piece of software is developed by "some guy" afaik.

Comment: thank you for your interest, I tried but it doesn't find other devices. I checked the other devices, they are connected but I couldn't find with arp-scan or my way. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Use netdiscover

```
netdiscover -i <interface>
```

If you're trying to find the devices in the wifi network, the command would be

```
netdiscover -i wlan0
```

Comment: Is interface a parameter or value? Should I run same form yours?

Comment: There was an extra space before that 'i', sorry about that. I removed it.

Comment: Doesn't matter, thank u so much, I'll try when I arrive to home

Answer (score 0):

Your command should have worked. It does on my system anyway, as does `arp-scan` as suggested by Adonis. If, however, you [don't want to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676836/how-to-find-other-machines-which-are-connected-same-network#comment981028_676842) any tools, you could use a brute approach and just ping everything:

```
for i in 192.168.1.{1..100}; do 
    ping -w 1 -c 1 $i >/dev/null && echo "$i is up"; 
done
```

The command above will ping every IP between `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.100`. If a host is pingable (if it is connected), it will print the host's name.

However, this will be slow and cumbersome and is not really a good solution. Use `arp-scan` or `nmap` as you did instead.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, all of you. Why isn't my command working on my  network but working on yours? It made me crazy.